# MVC3 Controller issue with '&' in value of a multi select jQuery object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C# .Net MVC3 web app.  We are populating the options of a multi select object from our database.  One of the items in our database that is being selected contains an '&' in the text.  The HTML for the select object when rendered looks like this:

```
<select id="myMultiSelect">
    <option value="Material">Material</option>
    <option value="SI&T">SI&T</option>
    <option value="PMO">PMO</option>
</select>
```

When posting back to the Controller,  if the user has selected the 'SI&T' option, only 'SI' is comingback as one of the values for myMultiSelect.  The user can select more than one option, thus the string[] for myMultiSelect.  Here's the Controller signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string[] myMultiSelect)
```

Do I need to Encode the value="SI&T"?  Or what is the fix?

**EDIT:**
Tried this but the valuoe returned to the Controller is still 'SI'

```
 $("#myMultiSelect").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "SI&amp;T").text("SI&T"));
```

Comment: HTML encode the & so that it becomes &amp;

Comment: @pkr298...yeah, I tried that.  I even hard coded it as a test and still came over to the Controller as 'SI'

Comment: Try to replace with `%26`.

Comment: @inanikian...if you like, go ahead and post your answer and I'll check it as Accepted.